# How to delete duplicated records on multi array on PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this issue with a multi array in PHP.
My array is recording a 60 rows CSV:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$totalrows;$i++){
  $row[$i][1]=record name;
  $row[$i][2]=record lastname;
  $row[$i][3]=record email;
  $row[$i][4]=record telephone;
  $row[$i][5]=record others;
}
```

First sort the records by a score I assigned for each field with information. And now I need to delete all duplicated emails ($row[$i][3]), but I don't know how.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `array_unique`

`<?php
$result = array_unique($row);
print_r($result);
?>`